# How to solve Cordova build android failure

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I was trying to build into android platform on cordova via `cordova build android` the thing is it wont continue to build it gives me this error thing
see image below for the error log
[image]
This is the 2nd day I'm trying to see how to fix it and yet got nothing .. I'm using Netbeans as my IDE running on fedora 23 OS
and all my Environments are available as per `cordova requirements` command
see image below
[image]
I really need some help here you guys please

**UPDATE**

I tried following the dir that the error gave me and run the command `sudo ./gradlew` and found that the `Android SDK` cant be found or something see image below
[image]

but the weird part is that when I run the `cordova requirements` its there the `Android Sdk` is there see image below

[image]

now its getting me all confused can someone tell me exactly whats happening now??

TIA

Comment: You missed blur of "your app name" on first image at bottom of red string. If its too important for you just wanted to warn

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz thanks for pointing that out..

Comment: Do you have any file names in your folders that have special characters?

Comment: @Dar no none at all

Comment: @KimOliveros Maybe you can double check to see if file names (including libaries, images) have characters that have accents (such as é), Japanese, Chinese, etc. Maybe spaces were ignored, etc. Also try `cordova clean android` before building again

Comment: To check where it's having problems with: in the terminal, go to your android directory. `projectName/platforms/android` Since you are using a Mac, try `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` Can you share where the error is?

Comment: Ok wait @Dar btw I'm on Fedora not Mac will that command work too?

Comment: @KimOliveros Oh! Sorry, I read wrong but it should work

Comment: @KimOliveros Could you try building browser platform to see whether it is working so that we can narrow down the issue?

Comment: @Gandhi its working fine on `cordova build browser`

Comment: @KimOliveros That narrows down the problem to be only with Android related. Try to do Build -> Clean Project and Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: @Gandhi tried it and no luck.. But upon running gradlew I found something which might have a meaning to experienced people like you on cordova I'll update my post for ref

Comment: @KimOliveros Have you set ANDROID_HOME system environment variable properly pointing to your android sdk installation folder?

Comment: @Gandhi hmm how do I verify that? because Im able to use emulators just fine

Comment: @KimOliveros Check this link's 'Install Android SDK' section - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development

Answer (score 0):

I cant give you a straight answer to whats breaking your build.
But for me 9/10 it was due to a plugin incompatibility.

**Troubleshooting -**

1. Ensure your Cordova version is latest
2. Ensure your plugins version is latest
3. Uninstall all your plugins and try and build

If **success** try installing your plugins one by one until you find the culprit.

If **fail** theres something wrong with either your Cordova or your Android Studios so just ensure you've set them up correctly and try again.

Comment: Hi Mark I have the latest version of cordova and tried that beforehand and also to your info I'm not using Android Studio. I've just downloaded the standalone sdk could that be an issue?

Comment: ah ha! Yeah Cordova uses Android Studios to build the app. Its like trying to build an iOS app without xCode :). Try and install it and let us know.

Comment: I see ok will update you guys soon will download it now

Comment: @Mark actually you can build without Android Studio. Having SDK alone will suffice unless you need some native tools or plugins

Comment: @Dar Ah yeah your right. Kim check out this and make sure you have set up Cordova correctly https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Comment: Yeah saw it and fails also